# Simplifying a list filter in Python

Tags: python, list, filter, generator

I'm trying to filter a list composed of multiple dictionaries for useless entries and non-ideal fields. An entry is useless if `Mem['visibility'] == "redacted"` and then should be removed from the list. An entry is non-ideal when any of the fields are empty, and these should be filled with a 0 instead or if `Mem['~whatever~']` is a list in which case the list should be transformed into a single string with all the objects in that list. I wrote the following code to do so:

```
class Filter:

    @staticmethod
    def members(memberlist):
        for Mem in memberlist:
            for Item in Mem:
                if not Mem[Item]:
                    Mem[Item] = 0
                if (type(Mem[Item]) is list):
                    Mem[Item] = ', '.join(Mem[Item])
            if(Mem['visibility'] == "redacted"):
                memberlist.remove(Mem)
        return(memberlist)
```

sample of memberlist:

```
[
    {'roles': [],
     'rank': 'No SCB account',
     'type': 'main',
     'stars': 2,
     'visibility': 'visible',
     'sid': 'imperium',
     'handle': 'freakyeagle'
    },
    {'roles': [],
     'rank': 'Fleet Member',
     'type': 'main',
     'stars': 1,
     'visibility': 'visible',
     'sid': 'imperium',
     'handle': 'cadimus'},
    {'roles': [],
     'rank': 'Fleet Member',
     'type': 'main',
     'stars': 1,
     'visibility': 'visible',
     'sid': 'imperium',
     'handle': 'belleal'}
]
```

How can I make this as simple/efficient as possible?

Also, for some reason when I remove the useless Mem from the list in the code above it breaks my insertion on the database that happens in the following function (the memberlist in the function above is equivalent to member in this one):

```
def member(conn, cursor, member):
    try:
        if type(member) is not list:
            # TODO: Eventually implement single member insert here.
            print(member)
        cursor.executemany("INSERT INTO `Citizens` (`Handle`,`Org`,`Role`, "
                           "`Rank`,`Visibility`,`Stars`,`Type`) VALUES "
                           "(%(handle)s,%(sid)s,%(roles)s,%(rank)s,"
                           "%(visibility)s,%(stars)s,%(type)s);", member)
        conn.commit()
```

Does anyone know why does this happen?

Comment: As an aside, never remove items from a list as you iterate over the list - that'll produce unexpected results as some items in the list are skipped.

Comment: What would be the best way to do it? Create a list of Mem to remove and then remove it afterwards?

Comment: Either iterate over a copy of the list (`for mem in memberlist[:]:`), or append the ones you _do_ want to keep to a new list and return that instead.

Comment: Just a note; if `Mem[Item]` is an empty list, you'll be converting it to `0` because `if not Mem[Item]:` returns True for an empty list.

Comment: @ozgur Where do you mean that?

Comment: Your line `if not Mem[Item]` will set every value that evaluates to False to 0 - that means empty lists (`[]`) as well as empty strings.

Comment: @Ben, your copy solution fixed the bug, thanks a bunch!

Comment: @Arengorn No worries, are you still having problems? If not I'll post it as an answer and you can accept it.

Comment: @Ben Just with the first question that still needs answer, whats the most efficient way to pass those filters, but not with the bug, no. About the `if not`, it's alright any empty fields, lists or strings should be converted to a `0`

Comment: If you don't have a bug or a problem, and all you're after is whether your code is efficient, it's probably better off asked on http://codereview.stackexchange.com :-)

Comment: Oh, my bad! Then post your answer and I'll accept it, thanks a bunch!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't remove items from a list as you're iterating over it - you'll get unexpected behaviour when items are skipped after you've removed an item.

Instead, either make a copy of the list to iterate over:

```
for mem in memberlist[:]:
    ...
```

Or save the results you want to another list and return that instead:

```
keep = []
for mem in memberlist:
    if ...:
       keep.append(mem)
return keep
```